# Is this algebra semisimple?

Tags: representation-theory

Is this algebra, A, semisimple? And what are its simple modules?

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&0&e\end{bmatrix} \subset M_3(k),$$ where $k$ is a field and $a,b,c,d,e$ are elements in $k$.

I know every non $0$  A-module is semisimple, so does it suffice to show that this is an A module? I'm very confused.

Comment: Closely related: [Why $R$ is semisimple ring iff every $R$-module is semisimple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055190/why-r-is-semisimple-ring-iff-every-r-module-is-semisimple)

Comment: $A\cong M_2(k)\oplus k$, which is semisimple.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. How do I do about finding the simple modules?

Answer (score 0):

There're two  well-known Theorems

1. A ring is semisimple iff all its  modules are semisimple.

2.A Finite dimensional semisimple algebra over a field k is a direct sum of matrix $M_{n_i}(D_i)$, where D is a division ring over k.

Comment: Thank you everyone. How do I go about finding the simple modules?