# Module over semisimple algebra

Tags: modules, representation-theory

In this context $R$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$ and $U$ is a finite dimensional $R$-module.
It goes $U/(\text{Rad}R \cdot U)$ is a module over $R/\text{Rad}(R) $ which is a semisimple algebra. Hence $U/(\text{Rad}R \cdot U ) $ is a semisimple module.

Why is this the case? I take it this must be some sort of general result about semisimple algebras?

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking why $U/(\text{Rad}R \cdot U )$ is a semisimple $R/\text{Rad}R$ module, then you can see why all modules of a semisimple ring are semisimple [at this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055190/29335).

If you are asking why it is a semisimple $R$ module, then that is because $R$ and $R/\mathrm{Rad}R$ have "the same simple modules."  Something is a direct sum of simple $R$ modules iff it is a direct sum of simple $R/\mathrm{Rad}(R)$ modules.

(Throughout I assume $\mathrm{Rad}(R)$ means the Jacobson radical, which I'd normally denote $J(R)$.  $\mathrm{Rad}$ is a bit more overloaded.)

Comment: Here the radical of $U$ is the intersection of all maximal submodules of $U$

Comment: Looks like i surmised right then.